# Error when updating SQLite database using VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqlite, sql-update, sharpdevelop

Trying to get this code to work so that it will update my SQLite database. Keep getting an error saying that an end of statement is expected error BC30205. I cannot see what i am missing! This is my first ever attempt at an update statement in SQL so i may have missed something obvious! I have marked the line of code i am having the error with with an arrow!

```
Public Partial Class Change_Password
Public Sub New()
    ' The Me.InitializeComponent call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
    Me.InitializeComponent()

    '
    ' TODO : Add constructor code after InitializeComponents
    '
End Sub

Dim SQLconnect As New System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection()
Dim SQLcommand As System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand
Dim SQLreader As System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader

Dim Password1 As String = ""
Dim Password2 As String = ""

Public Class Password
    Public shared usernamechange As String = ""
End Class

Sub Cmd_NextClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If Trim(txt_Password_Box.Text) = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a password")
    Else
        Password1 = txt_Password_Box.Text
        txt_Password_Box.Text = ""
        txt_Password_Box.Focus
        lbl_Instruction.Text = "Please re-enter the exact same password!"
        cmd_Submit.Visible = True
        cmd_Next.Visible = False
        Me.AcceptButton = cmd_Submit
    End If

End Sub

Sub Change_PasswordLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    cmd_Submit.Visible = False  
    Me.AcceptButton = cmd_Next
    SQLconnect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=KCD.s3db;"
    SQLconnect.Open()
End Sub

Sub Cmd_SubmitClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If Trim(txt_Password_Box.Text) = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter the password again")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Password2 = txt_Password_Box.Text
        txt_Password_Box.Text = ""
    End If



    If Password1 = Password2 Then

        SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand

------> SQLcommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Staff SET Password = '" & password1 & "' WHERE '" Username = "' & password.usernamechange & '"""



        SQLcommand.Dispose()

        MsgBox("Your password has been changed",vbInformation,"Password Changed")
        Me.Close

    Else

        MsgBox("Passwords do not match. Please try again.")
        txt_Password_Box.Focus
        cmd_Submit.Visible = False
        cmd_Next.Visible = True
        Password1 = ""
        Password2 = ""
        lbl_Instruction.Text = "Please enter a new password!"
        Me.AcceptButton = cmd_Next
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

Hope someone can help me! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line doesn't seem right. Change

```
SQLcommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Staff SET Password = '" & password1 & "' WHERE '" Username = "' & password.usernamechange & '"""
```

to

```
SQLcommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Staff SET Password = '" & password1 & "' WHERE Username = '" & password.usernamechange & "'"
```

BTW, concatenating strings like that leads to being vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Thank you! It got rid of the error but the statement doesn't actually do anything to the database! Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Run the select statement with the same where clause and see if it returns anything.

Comment: Yeah i get data when i run a select statement on the same form! I ran this statement

SQLcommand.CommandText = "SELECT Username FROM Staff WHERE Username = '" & username & "'"
         'Extract data
         SQLreader = SQLcommand.ExecuteReader()
         
         Dim test As String = SQLreader("Username")

Comment: Ah, ok. You were previously saying that the statement didn't return anything. But it's an update statement, it should not return anything.

Comment: Oh okay! Apologies for that! It's just not updating a pre existing record in the database!

Comment: It working in the database client i am working, just not when i send it from VB.Net! Is there an execute code i am missing or something?

Comment: I added that in and still no luck! :/

    If Password1 = Password2 Then
      
   SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand
   
   SQLcommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Staff SET Password = '" & Password1 & "' WHERE  Username = '" & username & "'"
   
   SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   
   SQLcommand.Dispose()
   
   MsgBox("Your password has been changed",vbInformation,"Password Changed")
   Me.Close

Comment: Just an update: I gave in working on it last night. Came back to it today and the code was working perfectly! Thank you very much for your help! :) Really appreciate it!